# Flutter Location packages does not return current location on iOS

Tags: flutter, location, future

I'm stuck with this problem, If I try to call:

```
Location location = Location();
LocationData data = await location.getLocation();
```

The future does never return anything, it just keeps going without returning values.
This is kinda weird because in my application I also have google maps and they find without a problem my position, so it is not a GPS / Permission problem.

On Android this problem does not exist, just on iOS (Targetting iOS 10.0 at the moment).

### Edit:

After more tests I concluded that it actually works, but just the first time the app is opened, every other request to that method does not respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it, if it happens to you check to do not call .getLocation() while a onChangedPosition listener is active.

Comment: @Palejandro , you can read more and fine some code i've wrote at this link: https://github.com/Lyokone/flutterlocation/issues/361#issuecomment-657766329

Answer (score 3):

i was struggling with this problem, and i get that this happen because location on simulator is stop. so you must make simulator location move. to make location of simulator move, open your X-code simulator -> on top corner of your macbook (beside apple logo), klik feature -> klik location -> choose free way drive

Answer (score 0):

To use it in iOS, you have to add this permission in Info.plist :

```
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
```

Comment: Yeah, I know, that's already done, sadly it doesn't work :)

Comment: Code is fine, those are the lines that give throuble, I tried to mock the location and the code keeps running properly as expected, when I try to use a real location (Or faked by the simulator, but still "real") it doesn't work 'cause .getLocation() does not return anything and onChangedLocation aswell. Permissions and service status are OK, I check and print them everytime I call getLocation()

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this for a while. Go to your simulator settings at the top bar, click the 'Features' ==> 'Location' pick from various locations to mock: [None, Custom Location, City Run, City Bicycle Ride, Freeway Drive, Apple].

Should work then provided Info.plist is properly set-up, and Android Manifest is correct.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).